# nodejs callback in a function - newbie query

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I have the following function to extract some variables from a html page and publish them via i/o which is working properly - but I want to add a callback to ensure that I can find out if this function has completed fully.

Please advise how i can add a callback purely for this purpose - since I don't have any other need of the callback.

```
function RunScrapingPositions() {
    status = false;
    myhttp.get('https://example.com/PB.jsp',
    function (_html) {
            if (_html && _html.length > 10) {          
            news.positions = {};
            $ = cheerio.load(_html);

            $('tr[id^="TR"]').each(function () {
                  status = true;
                  var symbol = $('td:nth-child(3)', this).text().trim();
                  var objob = {
                     'NQ': parseInt($('td:nth-child(11)', this).text().trim()),
                              };

                  var post = {
                        'symbol': symbol,
                        'nq': objob.NQ
                            };


            connection.query('INSERT INTO NP SET ?', post, function (err,result){
            if (err) 
            {console.log("NP sql insert error : " +symbol);}
            else {
                console.log("Posn - Step 3B - Position data inserted into NP Table : " +symbol);
                 }
        });




                var objstock = news.analysis[symbol];

                if (typeof objstock!='undefined') {
                    objstock.NQ = objob.NQ;
                    news.positions[symbol] = objob;
                    news.analysis[symbol] = objstock;

                if (status) {
                     console.log('Posn - Step 4 - Positions data pushed to page')
                     io.emit('news', news);

                            }
               }
                 else           
               {
               console.log('Posn - Step 4A - Position symbol not found');
               } 
            });


            if (timerPositions) {
                clearTimeout(timerPositions);
            }
            console.log('Posn - Step 5 - setTimer RunScrapingPositions:' + config.DelayExtractPositions);
            timerPositions = setTimeout(RunScrapingPositions, config.DelayExtractPositions);

        }

    });
}
```

Comment: It would help if you would indent your code properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a callback implemented with the following steps:

Accept a callback function as argument:

```
function RunScrapingPositions(callbackDone) {
```

Then, where you call it, pass that function on. You can use `bind`for that. And where you have the condition that all is done, call it:

```
function RunScrapingPositions(callbackDone) {
    status = false;
    myhttp.get('https://example.com/PB.jsp', function (_html) {
        if (_html && _html.length > 10) {
            // ... 

            // pass the callback function on to the deferred call:
            timerPositions = setTimeout(
                    RunScrapingPositions.bind(null, callbackDone),
                    config.DelayExtractPositions
            );
        } else {
            // all is done, call the callback function:
            callbackDone();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery's custom event facility, $(document).trigger({eventName}, obj or list of arguments), to trigger an "event". You can write code to listen for that event via $(document).on({eventName}, function(someArgsThatYouPass){do something here....}).